# Adding pagination to a DataGridView

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview, pagination

I am working on a VB project - net 2.0. It has been a long time since I have worked in .net and I need a little refresher.

How would I add pagination to this piece of code:

```
  'AdvDataGrid
    '
    Me.AdvDataGrid.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize
    Me.AdvDataGrid.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(881, 37)
    Me.AdvDataGrid.Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4)
    Me.AdvDataGrid.Name = "AdvDataGrid"
    Me.AdvDataGrid.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(661, 546)
    Me.AdvDataGrid.TabIndex = 67
```

Comment: maybe `.RowFilter` ? ;p , or as Levi suggested, pulling only a subset of records each time to the datasource. depends on size of data, and if it is local or remote.

Comment: oh, here's the MSDN example: `How To Perform Paging with the DataGrid Windows Control by Using Visual Basic .NET`: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305271/en-us although a bit dated, and it's for `DataGrid`.

Comment: also, check out this link: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/VBWinFormDataGridView-961db2a6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Portlight,
As you may know, pagination isn't an inherint element to the windows forms datagridview. However, with the bindingnavigator and binding source, you can achieve the results you are looking for.
I have researched this solution, that I found in C#. However, you can easily convert the code to vb.net. I instruct you to the original document so that you can follow and understand the concept.
Be mindful, the article has a link to StackOverflow for additional options and understanding.
Sorry, but pagination can not be added to your code - much is needed to achieve your results.
http://dotnetgenetics.blogspot.com/2013/11/datagridview-paging-using.html

Comment: maybe to make it even more efficient, you can have it continue to pull data async. maybe 5 more chunks, or just all of them, while the user views the page, to reduce subsequent loads. but that would require some fancy dataset management. then just copy chunks to a new dataset. or actually. you can just filter them at that point. i guess the key is to pull chunks async so user doesnt wait on 10,000 records.

Comment: do you have any information on setting up a data async?

Comment: Data async just means you load the data behind the scenes so the user isn't waiting on the loading to complete. Setting up your data calls and building efficiencies within the data pulls would be another thread.